# JPG not working on ASP Image

Tags: asp.net, image, url, png, jpeg

I have an Image object in ASP.NET
I am assigning an ImageUrl to it but I'm noticing that it does not display a thing when it's a format different from PNG.

In this case, I need it to accept JPG. What can be done?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>
                Foto
            </strong>

            <br/>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ToolTip="Foto" Width="320px" Height="240px" ImageUrl='<%# "C:/Images/pictures/" + Eval("picture") %>' />
        </td>

        <td />

        <td>
            <strong>
                Firma
            </strong>

            <br/>
            <asp:Image ID="imgSignature" runat="server" ToolTip="Firma" Width="320px" Height="240px" ImageUrl='<%# "C:/Images/signatures/" + Eval("signature") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

picture = 1.jpg
signarute = 2.png
```

the first one is not working, the second one does.
This is inside a gridview row.

Comment: Maybe the imageurl is incorrect. Maybe your image is corrupt. Can you post more information? Like the asp:image code, the rendered html, and the URL of the image if you navigate to it directly?

Comment: ALRIGHT, I have added the asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use physical file paths for images. You either need to use the absolute path, or more simply, the relative path, like `~/Images/signatures/myImage.jpg`:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgSignature" runat="server" ToolTip="Firma" Width="320px" Height="240px" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/signatures/" + Eval("signature") %>' />
```

Side note, you shouldn't use tables for layout / formatting. Use CSS.

Comment: **You can't use physical file paths for images** you should write **should not** should not use :)

Comment: You can't, if you expect it to work. That is implied. He can also plug his computer into a cat... That doesn't mean it'd turn on. Some things you shouldn't do, like use tables for layout. Other things you can't do, like in embedding a body tag inside a head tag. While it is *possible* to type such a thing, it's not a valid option and isn't worth discussing... aside from telling people not to. This is one of those times.